# Magento - Processing orders working slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I try to create invoices for orders it takes like 1-2 minutes until it finish the process. Some days ago worked ok.

I cleaned the log from the database and it started to work a little bit more ok.
On orders with more than 2 products (for example) still working slow.

Anybody can help me please?

Comment: Have you checked slow queries ? What software you're using for profiling your application ?

Comment: I don't have nothing for checking queries from admin. can you help me with something?

Comment: Please check in code is there were some print,var_dump,echo the variable

Comment: What are your technical skills ? I mean are you a developer ? or whop owner ?

Comment: I'm a developer. I managed to check for slow queries with the pdo_mysql.log . But after I truncated the log's tables it is working ok... Maybe I can check tomorrow if I still have the problem...

Comment: You can check this http://newrelic.com tool as for clearing tables you should check how many records you removed and think of disabling  Magneto log system as it's not very useful or in very rare occasions. PS. Logs can be disabled via config files.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.

I just deleted the logs.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
```

Somehow import/export/customer logs tables were very big.